# How to make Ruby Mocha mock only check about one parameter

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, mocking, automated-tests, ruby-mocha

I want to mock this function:

```html
def self.set_segment_info(segment_info, history_record)
  history_record.segment_info = segment_info
end
```

In my test, I want a mock that only confirms that I called set_segment_info with an expected value. I don't care about what I pass in for history_record.

How would I do this? I tried

```
SegmentHistoryRecord.expects(:set_segment_info).with(:segment_info => expected_segment_info, :history_record => anything)
```

But that doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this today and ended up doing something like:

```rb
SegmentHistoryRecord.expects(:set_segment_info).with(
   expected_segment_info, 
   anything
)
```

I find it more readable that the `do` version and it helped me avoid a rubocop issue with too many parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation where, if your function takes a *lot* of parameters, it's more convenient to specify a value for just the one you care about, instead of for *all* of them:

```
expected_segment_info = # ...
SegmentHistoryRecord.expects(:set_segment_info).with() { |actual_parameters| actual_parameters[:segment_info] == expected_segment_info }
```

(Where, as in the original question, `set_segment_info` is the function being mocked, and `segment_info` is the parameter whose value you want to match. Note that the `history_record` parameter -- and any others that might be present -- don't need to be included.)

Comment: This is pretty useful in case of keyword arguments

Answer (score 0):

```rb
SegmentHistoryRecord.expects(:set_segment_info).with() do |param1, param2|
  # change below to your verification for :segment_info
  # and leave param2 doing nothing, the expectation will ignore param2
  param1 == expected_segment_info
end
```